# R - Summarize data.frame on an interval

Tags: r, dataframe, summarize

I am trying to sum a variable on a data.frame for every Friday.

#### Random data frame

```
mydf = data.frame(      "ID"   = c( rep( "A" , 6) , rep( "B" , 5 ) ),   "Date" = c( "2017-09-08","2017-09-10","2017-09-13","2017-09-15","2017-09-20","2017-09-22","2017-08-03","2017-08-04","2017-08-10","2017-08-11","2017-08-12" , "Var"  = c( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,NA,10,11) )

mydf$Date = as.Date( mydf$Date )

mydf = cbind( mydf , "WeekDay" = weekdays( mydf$Date ) )
```

### What I want to get

```
df_ToGet = 
data.frame( 
    "ID"   = c( rep( "A" , 3) , rep( "B" , 2 ) ),
    "Date" = c( "2017-09-08","2017-09-15","2017-09-22","2017-08-04","2017-08-11"  ),
    "Var_Sum"  = c( 1 , 9 , 11 , 15, 10 )
    )
```

### What I tried

I have considered using *dplyr::summarize* and *aggregate* but I do not know how to set the *by* condition properly.

```
mydf %>% group_by( ID ) %>% summarize( Var_Sum = aggregate( Var , sum ,  by=list ( (mydf$Weekday)=="Friday") )  )
```

I have seen a few similar questions being solved using the *cut* function but that seems to be setting the condition to a standard week? I'm not too familiar with it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to create a grouping variable using `cumsum`

```
mydf %>%
    slice(seq_len(tail(which(WeekDay== "Friday"), 1))) %>% 
    group_by(ID, grp = lag(cumsum(WeekDay == "Friday"), default = 0)) %>% 
    summarise(Date = Date[WeekDay == "Friday"], Var = sum(Var, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-grp)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#     ID       Date   Var
#   <fctr>     <date> <dbl>
#1      A 2017-09-08     1
#2      A 2017-09-15     9
#3      A 2017-09-22    11
#4      B 2017-08-04    15
#5      B 2017-08-11    10
```

Comment: Looks like I was correct to ask this instead of figuring it out myself. Thanks. Is it possible to improve this to allow for multiple variables though? For example having 100 variables to summarize. If this requires asking a new question, let me know and I'll do that instead.

Comment: To summarize more variables use `summarize_all` or `summarize_each` instead of `summarize`.

Comment: Okay, got it. Cheers @danh